# jQuery post data partially sent to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have javascript code that gets an array of IDs and then sends them using ajax to PHP. For some reason out of 3 arrays that I send, the first one is never sent, so I always get an empty array in PHP, even though I have confirmed that the array is not empty before calling `$.post()`

Javascript:

```
$.post(
    "ajax.php",
    {
        deletedImageGUIDs: deletedImageGUIDs
        ,imageGUIDs: imageGUIDs
        ,categoryGUIDs: categoryGUIDs
    },
    function(data, status) {
        if (status == "success") {
             alert(data);   
             deletedImageGUIDs =  [];
             imageGUIDs = [];
             categoryGUIDs = [];                       
        }
        else {
             alert("There was an error saving changes");
        }
    }
);
```

ajax.php:

```
if(!($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")){
    die("Request Error");
}

$deletedImageGUIDs = isset($_POST["deleteImageGUIDs"])?$_POST["deletedImageGUIDs"] : array();
$imageGUIDs = isset($_POST["imageGUIDs"])?$_POST["imageGUIDs"] : array();
$categoryGUIDs = isset($_POST["categoryGUIDs"])?$_POST["categoryGUIDs"] : array();
```

`$deletedImageGUIDs` is always an empty array, while `$imageGUIDs` and `$categoryGUIDs` work fine.

Comment: Possibly you could check the requests in Chrome dev tools, so that you can see the request send from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following, u have typo.

```
$deletedImageGUIDs = isset($_POST["deletedImageGUIDs"])?$_POST["deletedImageGUIDs"] : array();
```

its not `deleteImageGUIDs` its, `deletedImageGUIDs`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see that.

Comment: Ahhh, Seems @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com is on the hunt for typos after last nights escapade. :P

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo. It should be `deletedImageGUIDs` instaed of `deleteImageGUIDs` -

```
$deletedImageGUIDs = isset($_POST["deletedImageGUIDs"])?$_POST["deletedImageGUIDs"] : array();
```

Comment: Wow how did I miss that. Thank you